# Where does Firefox cache HTML5 video?

Tags: firefox, video, browser, cache, browser-cache

Are HTML5 videos (ie MP4) like from YouTube, etc. stored in the normal Firefox browser cache or elsewhere?

I have a setting in my `about:config` to only store cache in RAM cause I don't like temporary junk wearing out my SSD. Does this mean the videos get cached in RAM too or not?

Comment: “…RAM cause I don't like temporary junk wearing out my SSD.” Where do you get the idea doing this will help your SSD? If video files are cached to RAM and the system runs out of RAM — or needs it for something else — where do you think the swap file will go? The system disk.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 1. I won't run out of RAM cause I have 64GB. 2. I have disabled the swap file completely.

Comment: “I won't run out of RAM cause I have 64GB.” And how much of that RAM is used by the system? Let’s say 4GB to 8GB. That leaves you with 56GB at best. Let’s say that we roll that down by 6GB for other apps and such, so you now have 50GB. If you are watching SD videos or 1080 HD videos, *maybe* you are doing beneficial. But if you are watching 4K HD videos, then you will run out of RAM. And the lifespans of modern SSDs are solid. You will most likely sell your system or upgrade the SSD waaaay before you wear the system out. So I understand the desire to protect hardware, but this seems silly.

Answer (score 3):

If you would watch 4k movies @ 60 fps 24/7 you have to cache about 100GB per day (~1.15 MB/s). Under those conditions, a "recent" 500GB SSD with 3k write cycles will last about 40 years (sic!), before it fails.

So just enjoy using your SSD and do not worry about wearing it out.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not a big deal, but I'd still like to know where it is. Even if it's not bad for it, the thought of stuff getting fragged over time isn't nice. I know fragmentation doesn't matter for SSD, but it's just something that bothers me. Call me crazy.

Comment: The thing is: you try to mitigate sth. that is already taken care of by the browser, the filesystem, the OS, the SSD's firmware and the SSD's controller and for this you configure your system in an unusual way, which will more likely than not cause weird behavior. Trading an expanded lifetime of your SSD (which you will replace way before it reaches it, anyway), against an unstable and less performant system is nothing I would recommend.

Answer (score 3):

I checked Firefox forums and it seems like videos get cached in the Firefox cache folder along with anything else. So I wouldn’t know why HTML5 videos would get any special treatment.

I assume that if you're setting cache files to be stored in RAM then that’s where they’ll go and your SSD should be safe from all those junk files.